# Euclidean distance in a 3 dimentional room - based on a 2d array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to calculate the distances between points in a three dimentional room that are stored in a 2d array. The points are generated randomly and we assume that for all of the points it is possible that they are located in a 3d space. The points would have three parameters, like shown here: [[3.0, 5.0, 8.0], [6.0, 5.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0, 9.0], [8.0, 0.0, 3.0]]

I have come so far I think, but I seem to get into the array wrongly. Would you have any suggestion? I am getting index out of bounds.

public class Points {

```
public static class points {

    static String distanceBetweenPoints(int a) {
        // int a = number of Points

        int columns = 3;
        // every point has three coordinates x,y,z 

        double[][] points = new double[a][columns];

        // generating the points with random method:

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                points[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }

        double[][] distances = new double[points.length][points.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < distances.length; j++ )
                for (int l = 0, m = 0; j < points[0].length; l++, m++) {
                    distances[i][j] = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((points[i][k] - points[l][k]),2)
                            + Math.pow((points[j][1] - points[l][1]), 2)
                            + Math.pow((points[j][2] - points[l][2]), 2)));

            }
    }

        return Arrays.deepToString(distances);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(distanceBetweenPoints(4));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have a static class `points` inside a `class Points` and in it a `points` array. This is very bad practice. Never name a class with a name that starts with a lowercase letter. What is that class for anyway?

Comment: What is `k` for? It is always `0`. --- What is `m` for? It is never used. --- How did you envision 3rd loop would ever end, given that `j` never changes inside that loop? Perhaps you meant `l < points[0].length`? --- BTW: Do not name a variable `l` (letter ELL), as it is too easily confused with `1` (digit ONE).

Answer (score 1):

Putting a simple

```
System.out.println( String.format( "i: %d, j: %d, k: %d, l: %d, m: %d", i, j, k, l, m) );
```

into your code would show you your error immediatley. In the fourth iteration of inner loop the l gets 4, which is bigger than the size of the points-array.

You have a mess which indices are declared, checked and incremented in which loop.

Comment: And for comparing _pairs_ of points, only **two** nested loop should be needed.